# How to supress error printed out by try except block in python

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I've a try except block within a try except block in python and I want to suppress the error message printed to the screen if the try block doesn't succeed. My code structure is as follows:

```
try:
#doing something
except Exception:
  try:
    #doing something else
  except Exception:
    print("Some message")
  else:
    print("Success")
else:
  print("Success")
```

What happens right now is that an `ERROR` message gets printed to the screen by Python indicating what I'm doing in the `try` statement failed. I'm trying to find a way to suppress this.

Comment: You shouldn't see any error messages from Python if the exception gets handled by an `except` block. Can you update your question with a reproducible code example where Python can actually output error messages despite your error handlers?

Comment: same, I dont see any error messages.

Comment: So I'm trying to do an action by SSH'ing into a system in the `try` block which fails.  Unfortunately i can't copy the exact code due to it being some sensitive code.